# How to send a JSON as a body to a request in place of a xml ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, json, http

I was sending xml file as a body before stated as follows:

```
[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><vs:ClientID version=\"0.4\" xmlns:vs=\"http://www.@@@@@@.com/schemas/store\">%@</vs:ClientID>", openUDID] UTF8String];
```

Now i need to send the same body as a JSON for the request.
How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by creating a dictionary of data you want to send

```
NSMutableDictionary *reqDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[reqDictionary setValue:@"yourValue1" forKey:@"YourKey1"];
[reqDictionary setValue:@"yourValue2" forKey:@"YourKey2"];

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:fieldsArray options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted  error:&error];

NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Now the jsonString is the final string you want to post